# When I open .doc file giving me error like could not open this document this file isn't available offline

Tags: android

> Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); Intent intent = new
> Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
>
> if (file.toString().contains(".doc") ||
> file.toString().contains(".docx")) {
>
> intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
> activity.startActivity(intent); }

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` has not worked well in years. Use `FileProvider`.

Comment: Can you please provide any link .

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider  https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html